# Bluetooth communication between computer and nxt using RobotC

Tags: nxt, bluetooth, robotc

I'm thinking  starting a project involving controlling the movement of a NXT robot from the PC using RobotC.

Is it possible? Does anyone have a simple code solution?

Answer (score -2):

It's possible. simply make a BT connection and then use the control interface from your computer

Comment: Are there any other steps to this? Ideally we're looking for substantial answers that provide a bit of detail - possibly mention libraries or API calls?